# have_comments() returns false [with comments_template()]

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress installation is behaving very strangely. First the [recent posts stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710067/wp-get-recent-posts-stopped-working), now this...

I'm working on my custom wordpress theme and I got stuck on the comments. Actually, I just copied the code for the comments template and the 3 functions from [this tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/07/01/wordpress-theme-comments-template-tutorial/).

I found a solution that says I should call the template with comments_template() instead of the general include method and that is how I do it. It still doesn't show a single comment, even though get_comments_number() returns 2 and I see the comments in the dashboard.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I know it's a bit late to the game, but are you still struggling?

Comment: I don't remember how I fixed it, but currently I use FB comments on my blog, so no worries.

Answer (score 7):

I did suck with this also 5 mins ago.

Yes, you should call this `comments_template()` function.

Call it like this:

```
comments_template( '', true);
```

and then make a `comments.php` in your theme directory, and do the

```
 if (have_comments()) {
    ...
}
```

cycle.

It should work.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. There's something strangely wrong with my WP installation (or theme).

Comment: THANKS!  I was using get_template_part('comments') and it was allways false.  You use that function for everything else, but it seems you have to use comments_template() for comments.  THANKS!!!!